# Custom elements and package name

Tags: android, custom-attributes

When creating a custom element with attributes in Android I need to put the namespace of the application in the layout.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.example.mypackage"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.example.mypackage.MyCustomView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      whatever:my_custom_attribute="Hello, world!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Does this also requires that the structure of my project in Eclipse be the same as the name of the Android package as definied in the Manifest - as per the example?
Would this work too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.mycompany.myproduct"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <org.example.mypackage.MyCustomView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:gravity="center"
      whatever:my_custom_attribute="Hello, world!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the package name of your application that should be reflected. So its correct to use it as you are doing.

For example:

In `xmlns:whatever="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.mycompany.myproduct` the last part `org.mycompany.myproduct` should be the same as your **package name**. And you may change `xmlns:whatever` to anything like `xmlns:theblitz` but then make sure you do use `theblitz` as a prefix for your attributes in the xml.

For more info, read [this](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/)

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant (or I misunderstood your answer). In the first example, I used "org.mycompany.myproduct" both in the xmlns decleration AND in the declaration of the customer element. In tthe second one, the package in the custom element is "org.example.mypackage" and not "org.mycompany.myproduct".

Comment: the view type `org.example.mypackage.MyCustomView` is defined in the same way as your class file is located

Comment: So, that and the value in the xmlns don't have to match - right?

Comment: xmlns only needs to reflect package name. but the view type should reflect the full class path. So yes, both cant be matched as same